# How do I store colored text in a variable and print it with color later?

Tags: bash, shell-script, colors, git, escape-characters

If I do `git status --short`, git lists files that are not tracked with two red question marks in front:

[image]

I'm trying to store this in a variable and print it with color later. Here's my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
status=$(git status --short)
echo -e "$status"
```

I thought the `-e` flag would cause bash to color the output, but it isn't working:

[image]

How can I do this?

Edit: the possible duplicate is asking how escape characters, specifically ANSI color control sequences, work. I think I understand how they work. My question is how to preserve those in the script output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [printing colored text using echo](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43408/printing-colored-text-using-echo)

Comment: @jasonwryan please see my edit.

Comment: related http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44266/how-to-colorize-output-of-git

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most programs that produce color will, by default, only produce it when the output is to a terminal, not a pipe or file.  *Generally, this is a good thing.*  Often, however, there is an override switch.  For example, for `ls`, one can use `--color=always` and, as a result, color can be saved in shell variables.  For example:

[image]

`grep` also supports the `--colors=always` option.

For git, the corresponding option is its `color.ui` configuration setting:

```
git -c color.ui=always status
```

Comment: `git status` doesn't have a `--color` option. Is there any way to trick it into keeping the colors?

Comment: @Koveras For git, it seems that you have to change the defaults.  I found some documentation [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Colors-in-Git).  See the part that mentions "You can also set it to always to ignore the difference between terminals and pipes."

Comment: @Koveras Also see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44283/53604

Comment: That works - can you include that in your answer?

Comment: @Koveras I updated the answer with the git config commands.

Comment: Or just run `git -c color.ui=always log`.

Comment: @lcd047 Excellent!  I added the `-c` approach to the answer.

Comment: Yes, but `-c` doesn't "change the defaults", it just overrides them for the current command.

Comment: @lcd047 That is what "change the defaults for one command at a time" was supposed to mean.  Hmm.  I suppose I should rephrase.